# An error of hive handles column of timestamp in struct?

Tags: hadoop, struct, hive, timestamp

I am in GMT +0800.
When I use hive to process column of timestamp, if this column is in a struct type column,  there will be the following.

```
hive> desc ts;
t                       timestamp                                   
s                       struct<t_struct:timestamp>                      

hive> select * from ts;
1970-01-01 08:00:00 {"t_struct":"1970-01-01 00:00:00"}
```

and I insert a new line:

```
hive> insert into ts select * from ts;
```

show the table data again:

```
hive>  select * from ts;
1970-01-01 08:00:00 {"t_struct":"1969-12-31 16:00:00"}
1970-01-01 08:00:00 {"t_struct":"1970-01-01 00:00:00"}
```

The colunm `tstruct` is wrong.
What should I do to solve this problem?

ps:When I use spark SQL to connect hive not find the mistake.
But with MR or Tez find the mistake.

thinks.

Comment: Try to use STRING instead of Timestamp data type for the same

Comment: @leftjoin, hive doesn't support timestamp in struct?

Comment: @Arunachalam It can be a timezone issue. Hive works with timezones strange. And I do not know how to fix similar issues except using STRING. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51591735/2700344